# Updating attribute in Magento install script

Tags: php, magento, entities

I am trying to update a custom attribute via a Magento script. All I need to do is change the label of the attribute, which is on the customer table.

I've found online that the main things to make sure of is the naming of the upgrade scripts, and the corresponding version in the `config.xml` file too.

Every time I try, the core_resource does get an upgrade / bump in version number correctly, but the label doesn't change. I assume it's something in my upgrade script. What am I doing wrong? Do I need to reference the attribute differently?

In the DB `core_resources`:

```
Equisolve_GenisysUserId_setup  |  0.1.4  |  0.1.4
```

The `config.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
   <modules>
       <Equisolve_GenisysUserId>
           <version>0.1.4</version>
       </Equisolve_GenisysUserId>
   </modules>
   <global>
       <resources>
           <Equisolve_GenisysUserId_setup>
               <setup>
                   <module>Equisolve_GenisysUserId</module>
                   <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
               </setup>
               <connection>
                   <use>core_setup</use>
               </connection>
           </Equisolve_GenisysUserId_setup>
           <Equisolve_GenisysUserId_write>
               <connection>
                   <use>core_write</use>
               </connection>
           </Equisolve_GenisysUserId_write>
           <Equisolve_GenisysUserId_read>
               <connection>
                   <use>core_read</use>
               </connection>
           </Equisolve_GenisysUserId_read>
       </resources>
   </global>

</config>
```

Original install file at `install-0.1.0.php`:

```
<?php
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

$entityTypeId     = $setup->getEntityTypeId('customer');
$attributeSetId   = $setup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
$attributeGroupId = $setup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId);

$installer->addAttribute("customer", "genisys_user_id",  array(
    "type"     => "varchar",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Genisys User ID",
    "input"    => "text",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "default"  => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"   => false,
    "note"     => "The Reference ID to the customer within Genisys / AlphaRENTAL to connect their user account with their existing information and orders."
    )
);


$setup->addAttributeToGroup(
    $entityTypeId,
    $attributeSetId,
    $attributeGroupId,
    'genisys_user_id',
    '999'  //sort_order
);

$gUserAttribute = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "genisys_user_id");
$gUserAttribute->setData('used_in_forms', array('adminhtml_customer'));
$gUserAttribute->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true);
// Other options can be found in the customer_form_attribute database table; setting this data is required

$gUserAttribute->save();

$installer->endSetup();
?>
```

Upgrade script at `upgrade-0.1.3-0.1.4.php`:

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->updateAttribute('customer','genisys_user_id','label', 'Genisys Customer Number');
$installer->endSetup();
?>
```

I know there is a gap in version numbers; there were files in between. The upgrade to 0.1.4 "ran" as evidenced by the `core_resources` version...but the label hasn't updated.

Thanks for the insight!

Comment: Did you make any errors when you first ran upgrade 0.1.4? For example, did you create 0.1.4 then realise you'd forgotten something; then amended it and saved it but not updated it to a newer version? Even changing one character you're best off creating a new one (0.1.5 for example).

Answer (score 4):

I believe you need to make a small tweak to **upgrade-0.1.3-0.1.4.php** script

Simply modify `updateAttribute` arguments to use `frontend_label` (instead of `label`):

```
…
$installer->updateAttribute('customer', 'genisys_user_id', 'frontend_label', 'Genisys Customer Number');
…
```

I was facing this same problem as the OP and finding this question indicated that there was something unintuitive happening.

While `addAttribute(…)` expects a `label` key in the attribute-array it seems that `updateAttribute(…)` does not understand `label` as the field-argument.

I checked the `eav_attribute` table and found that there is no `label` column but there is a `frontend_label` column:

[image]

<s>I can't draw much of a conclusion as to why these two seemingly cohesive methods have this disconnect but hopefully this helps others with the same problem.</s>

See: http://www.webguys.de/magento-1/eav-attribute-setup for the nitty gritty.